# ¿Como puedo llamar un fragment que esta en un Navigation desde un Activity?

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo un `Activity` el cual tengo el método para modificar datos, en el método `onResponse` quiero llamar un `fragment` lo tengo desde un `Navigation component` ya que ese muestra la lista de detalles una ves ya modificado, lo estoy haciendo de de la siguiente forma pero me sale un error.

**Activity Modificar_viveres.java**

```
            public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(Modificar_viveres.this,response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            
            //Lo estoy tratando de llamar de esta forma
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.lista_viveres);

        }
```

**Error**

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: View com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton{c44f5d7 VFED..C.. ........ 15,726-465,824 #7f09008c app:id/btn_modificar} does not have a NavController set`